# C# How to handle large lists of data quickly

Tags: c#

I have tried to find some articles on my problem, but haven't found anything that is relevant or that makes sense for my application. Here is my issue:

I have two lists of (> 20,000) items.

I need to check each item in each list against every item in the opposite list.

An implementation of something like this:

```
    foreach(var item1 in List1)
    {
         foreach(var item2 in List2)
         {
              // Check item 1 against item 2. 
              // Check item 2 against item 1.
         }
    }
```

is extremely slow and unusable because of the work done for the checks.

Is there a more efficient way to handle these large lists of items that need a check like this?

Please let me know if there is more information I can provide.
Thanks for any help/ suggestions.

I am using C# .NET 3.5

EDIT: Let me try and explain the checks in brief way.

item1 and item2 are part of a pathing system. item1 and item2 are connected by N number of other items. I am checking if item1 is connected (valid path) to item2, and item2 is connected to item1. It cannot be assumed that if item1 -> item2, than item2 -> item1. So both checks are necessary.

The database contains the information if and how item1 -> item2 and if/how item2 -> item1.
Inside the check, there is a named pipe call to a service to do the check. The service does all the path checking and returns if item1 -> item2, etc.

Comment: If there's a large corpus of data and there's a database in the mix, can you perform some up-front filtering in the database before proceeding to iterate through all the data?

Comment: Please provide more information about the lists. Are the values unique? If so you should use hashsets; the framework hashset implementation has efficient set compare operations.

Comment: Logically you are doing some kind of "join" and you should implement it that way, using the mechanisms (and optimizations) built into your DB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid situation when for each iteration goes request to database. When possible try to make all in one query outside the loop, or fetch needed data outside the loop and then make your checks on this data.

All depends from checks operations. So describe them. But anyway, if your iterations are independent you can also parallelize your loops using PLINQ and Task Parallel Libary

[Data Parallelism (Task Parallel Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx)

[How to: Write a Simple Parallel.ForEach Loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the links, and they seem useful except its only available in .NET 4.0 and we are restrticted to 3.5.

Comment: I haven't noticed that you are using .NET 3.5. For .NET 3.5 TPL is impossible to use. But parallelize loop iterations is possible. When single iteration takes long time and is independent from each other, than for .NET 3.5 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem should be used and Wait handles to wait for all iterations end. So it the same as Data Parallelism in TPL, but manually made.

Answer (score 5):

That's an `O(N * M)` check.

If you're just comparing for equality on some key or other, then you can get away with O(N + M) iterations, assuming a reasonable hash code and a good distribution of keys. The simplest way to do this in .NET is with a LINQ join:

```
var pairs = from x in List1
            join y in List2 on x.Key1 equals y.Key2
            select new { x, y}; // Or whatever

foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    // Process each match
}
```

Of course, if you're *not* checking for equality, this doesn't help... but it's pretty much impossible to give any concrete help without more context.

Answer (score 2):

Long loop + database queries = terrible performance.

What you should attempt to do is to run some queries first, get the data you need, and then do the N x M checks against that data.

This isn't necessarily possible, of course; really depends on the kinds of checks you're doing.

Comment: Im not sure this is possible given my conditions. Each item1 has to go to the service called in the check to validate the route.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest converting both sides into hash tables (O(n)) for each table and scan through each list and do the O(1) look up in the other table to check if it contains the current item (o(n) overall).  this results in a O(n) overall.

I've done something similar with lists of ~1,000,000 and it usually finishes in the ~1 second range from what I remember.

Answer (score -1):

Lambda expressions and Linq

I would save time and stay away from loops. I'm sure whatever you're trying to achieve can be accomplished with LINQ queries.

For example to find a value within another collection or to find a collection of items within another collection.

Here is an example how to get a collection of items that is contained in another collection by ID for example, sorted by Name:

```
var result = from x in List1
         where (from c in List2
                select c.Id).Contains(x.Id)
                select x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Name);
```